# Airflow skipped dag run mail notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, triggers, notifications, airflow

Is there any option in AWS airflow to get alert mail for the skipped dag runs.

In my case, for a dag there are four task and every time run is getting skipped at third task.i have added failure_callback function to get notifications for the failed dag runs.The third task is getting skipped and there is no alert notification  for the skipped dag runs. Is there any possible ways to get notification for the skipped dag runs

.

```
Every time the third task is skipped and the fourth task is in 'no status' state. So there is no execution in the fourth task. Is there any way to get it mail for the no status dag runs. Or is there any way to get the mail notification for the skipped ones. 


def failire_callback():
     if task_name is 't1':
         print(" OUTPUT : t1 is failed")
     elif task_name is 't2':
         Print(" OUTPUT : t2 is failed")
     elif task_name is 't3':
         print(" OUTPUT : t3 is failed")
     else 
         Print("OUTPUT : t4 is failed")
      subject = Dag has failed
      message = generate_html_template
      send_email(to=IDs, subject = subject, html_content = message)


default_args = (
      Provide_context = True
      on_failure_callback = failure_callback
      dag = dag
)
```

Comment: There was a somewhat related discussion a little while back where [support for an on_skipped_callback was given](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/30264#issuecomment-1505759049). I just opened a [feature request](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/35936) for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently an out of the box way to alert on tasks being skipped. You can see the list of available callbacks [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html#callback-types).